# Sencha touch itemTpl, not display a row on condition basis

Tags: sencha-touch, itemtemplate

I want to not show a row in itemTpl if the value = 'xxx'.

Example :

```
itemTpl: '{title}',
data: [
    { title: 'Item 1' },
    { title: 'Item 2' },
    { title: 'Item 3' },
    { title: 'Item 4' }
]
```

here if title == 'Item 2' mean I should not display the row. need to skip it.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Here in your view, make following changes:

```
xtype: 'list',
id: 'myList',
//itemTpl: '{title}',
data: [
    { title: 'Item 1' },
    { title: 'Item 2' },
    { title: 'Item 3' },
    { title: 'Item 4' }
]
```

Inside the initialize() function of your view write:

```
var myList = Ext.getCmp('myList');
myList.setItemTpl([
      '<tpl if="title!=\'Item 2\'">',
      '{title}',
      '<tpl else>',
      '',
      '</tpl>'
]);
```

I think, this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what component you were using to display the data.

If you're using a list (and the data exists in a Store), you could use [filterBy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy) to simply filter the list, effectively not showing your row.

If you were using another component where it's outputting raw HTML, you'd have to use conditional logic in your XTemplate for the itemTpl.